# setup a dataframe to measure tumour volumes

Tags: python, pandas

I need to measure tumour volumes before and after a treatment. I want to construct the recording of the volumes by date efficiently and then analyse the tumour doubling time (the time the tumour takes to double in volume) using Pandas or similar.
I am a surgeon and treat [acoustic neuromas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vestibular_schwannoma) with [Gamma Knife radiosurgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiosurgery#Gamma_Knife).The tumours typically grow at 1 to 2 mm each year in diameter. They are usually followed up with MRI scans until they show growth (in the UK) and are treated and are then followed up by MRI scans for 10 years at least.

I'm sure the data collection is relatively simple but want to optimise it for efficiency afterwards. I was thinking of just using Excel and then importing the CSV into Pandas. The spreadsheet needs to be simple because it will be on a network drive within the hospital accessible from any PC for a number of people to do the volumetric assessment. This is done by drawing around the tumour on individual slices of the MRI scan and then getting the MRI scan to compute the volume of the regions of interest.

I am fairly novice at Python and Pandas. The complexity for me will be to do the datetime calculations to look at pre-treatment growth, and then post treatment growth and calculate volume doubling times.

I need to do this for about 250 patients so the time-consuming element is the volumetric assessment. On average there will be 3 to 4 pre-treatment scans and up to 10 post-treatment scans, so the data frame will be 250 records with about 15 pairs of date and volume paired columns, or similar.
Any suggestions welcome. I was just going to do it in FileMaker pro but I don't have a site license et cetera et cetera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple CSV data format, like the one shown below, will allow you easily capture and process data. Once captured, you can read this data into pandas with [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
 patient_id, date, scan_type, volume
    1, 1/1/2021, pre-treatment, 1
    1, 2/1/2021, post-treatment, 2
    1, 3/1/2021, post-treatment, 3
    2, 1/1/2021, pre-treatment, 4
    2, 2/1/2021, post-treatment, 5
```